# How to stop pygame from displaying unwanted text symbols?

Tags: python-2.7, text, pygame

I'm currently working on a game and on my pause screen I have it use my draw text function to display "Paused" as well as what is in my inventory( a list with the string of what was "picked up"). When it draws my inventory text it displays these box like symbols, here's what it looks like 
"You have: []'key'[]"
I tried using string.strip() to remove these [] [], but to no avail. Can anyone tell my why it is doing this and how to fix it?
[Here is my rendered string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA6W7.png).

```
if (self.paused):
    self.screen.blit(self.dim_screen, (0, 0))
    self.draw_text("Paused", self.title_font, 105, RED, WIDTH / 2, 
    HEIGHT / 2, align="center")
    self.draw_text("You have:{}".format(self.inv), self.title_font, 30, 
    GREEN, 50, HEIGHT - 50, align="nw")
pg.display.flip()
```

edit: it seems that the {} for .format are what is causing the blocks I removed them to see if it would properly render self.draw_text("You have:" + self.inv...
although it failed to concatenate, the blocks where gone.
I also changed fonts and it changed from blocks to parenthesis

Comment: You'd have to show us the string you are rendering. My guess is, some character is not available in the font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your font can't render `[` or `]`. Try replacing your `draw_text()` arguments:

```
self.draw_text("You have: " + ", ".join(self.inv), self.title_font, 30, 
               GREEN, 50, HEIGHT - 50, align="nw")
```

E.g.

```
>>> inv = ["key", "knife"]
>>> "You have:{}".format(inv)
"You have:['key', 'knife']"
>>> "You have " + ", ".join(inv)
'You have key, knife'
```

Comment: You're welcome, if you want to aggressively handle unprintable characters, there are modules like [slugify](https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify) available.